# Apache Nutch fetch and updatedb stages

Tags: java, apache, parsing, html-parsing, nutch

I've got a question about the way Nutch obtains links to update the crawldb with.

The command in question is `bin/nutch updatedb crawl/crawldb $s1`

I need to write a custom parser, before doing so I've examined Nutch's source code and as far as I'm concerned I'm responsible for providing the links to update the crawldb, by extracting it from the document and putting in as Outlink[] in the ParseData. At least that's what I understood from [this](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/plugin/parse-html/src/java/org/apache/nutch/parse/html/HtmlParser.java).

Correct me if I'm wrong, because I wouldn't like my crawler to stop after the first iteration, as it wouldn't have links to update the crawldb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nutch uses either `parse-html` or `parse-tika` to parse your crawled URLs (usually HTML) in this phase the outlinks are extracted and stored, when you execute a new iteration of the crawler Nutch will select some of the available (extracted) links to continue the crawl, you'll only need to write your own parser if you need to extract additional information from the web, let's say that you want all `h1` titles in a separate field, for instance.

If you take a look at the crawl script (https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/bin/crawl#L246) you'll see that the updatedb command will be executed once per iteration, so if you're using `parse-html` or `parse-tika` the outlinks of an HTML document (among others) are automatically extracted for you.

Comment: So I was right with the Outlinks[], yes? The links that I put there will be used in the next iteration, right?

Comment: Not exactly in the next iteration, there are a couple more of things involved (scoring) and the logic in the generator, but yes if you put some links in the `Outlinks[]` then it *could* be available for the next iteration, depending on the scoring, the `-topN` parameters, etc. Keep in mind that URL filters could exclude some of the URLs depending on your configuration.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i needed to know.